# Generate RDLC Report with two columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, report, rdlc

I need to build a report (.RDLC in visual studio 2012) that contais a long text in two columns by page.

I can't just add a new column in the report, because the content above of this long text will be dynamically, so,  this control (to fill the text in the second column) must be dynamically too.

Also, i need to add others parts of the report after the text ends.

Somebody knows how to do this?

Comment: You can't add a column (via Report.Columns) because this property will reflect on the entire report and you need to add other parts before and after the text. Just an idea (not tested): if you have a single long text to display, try calculating its length at runtime and split it in two textboxes placed next to each other (pay attention to not split a single word).